# Prevent ownership transfer for Account

Tags: apex

I have a usecase where owners should not be changed for standarad Account object.
I put a validation rule for these. and it works as well.But then came across this statement

> If the Mass Transfer tool is used to change the ownership of multiple
>   records, however, validation rules won’t run on those records.

what does it mean? Does it mean if i use mass transfer tool my validation rule will fail?

I should go for a trigger in this case?

If a trigger is there a way to understand the context is 'mass transfer tool' .so that i can trigger only in that context?

Comment: Your validation rule will not fail, instead it will be skipped (will not execute). It's SF standard functionality that overrides all user validations when changing ownership. 

You are definitely looking at a trigger in order to fire this 'validation' for multiple records at a time, though not sure if you can only run the trigger in 'mass transfer' context.

Answer (score 2):

As @e-bacho 2.0 mentioned in the comment above, you will need a trigger for this particular use case. You will want to implement a **before update** trigger that checks the current Account Owner against the previous value of that field, and if they do not match leverage the **[.addError(String)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_SObject_addError.htm)** method to add an error to the Account.

```
trigger preventTransferOwnership on Account (before update)
{
  for (Account a : Trigger.new)
  {
    if (a.OwnerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).OwnerId)
    {
      a.addError('Cannot transfer ownership of Account');
    }
  }
}
```

**Single Account Transfer Ownership:**

[image: Single Account Ownership Transfer]

**Mass Transfer Ownership:**

[image: Mass Transfer Ownership]